# Aligning background images with thumbnails

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I'm trying to get some vertical lines/stripes to appear as a background element on my [website](http://pistolpete2015.tumblr.com). I want these stripes to line up perfectly with the image thumbnails, but they're always a touch off.

Currently I'm using a solid background image, with the following code:

```
background: url(http://antiformat.org/apercu/grod.png) repeat-y center;
```

Is there a better way to line these up so that they'll *always* be in line with the left and right sides of my thumbnails? It'd be great if they stayed in that position even when the browser window is resized.

Image for reference here [image](http://antiformat.org/apercu/align.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide some code please? A fiddle would be great too.

Comment: what is the expected output can you show as image representation?

Comment: @will code should be above? not sure what you mean by fiddle? thanks.

Comment: jsfiddle.net is a site that's great for making small coding examples. You can add css, html, and javascript, save it, and post a link here.

Comment: Structure with tables and assign the bacground-image to the tables instead of the body